# How to make a button's content editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am wondering how can I make the content of a `<button>` editable? I already tried making a `<div>` which is `contenteditable = True` but I can't seem to work it out. Can someone show me how to do it?

EDIT:

```
$('#button')
            .click(function(eventClick, posX, posY){
                posX = typeof posX !== 'undefined' ? posX : null;
                posY = typeof posY !== 'undefined' ? posY : null;

                var htmlData='<div id="btn'+$.count+'" class="data-page="' + $.page + '"';

                htmlData += '><button id="editable'+$.count+'" style="width:100%; height:100%">move me, resize me</button></div>';

                $('.demo').append(htmlData);
                $('#btn2').resizable({grid: 10})
                .draggable({cancel:false, grid: [ 10,10 ] });
                $('#editable2').click(function(){
                    if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') ) {
                    return;
                    }
                    $(this).draggable( "option", "disabled", true);
                    $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
                })
                .blur(function(){
                    $(this).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', false);
                    $(this).attr('contenteditable','false');
                })
        });
```

So when a button is clicked, it creates this supposedly editable button, but it's not working.

Comment: which content to be editable

Comment: what you have tried before?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post. That's my snippet of code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use like this:

```
<button contenteditable>button</button>
```

NOT:     `<button contenteditable=true>button</button>`

> Note: This support only refers to very basic editing capability, implementations vary significantly on how certain elements can be edited. [source: can I use](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).attr('contentEditable', true); // with capital 'E' ; no quotes around true
```

or

```
$(this).get(0).contentEditable = true;
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/uZU9c/. Are you sure `$('#editable2')` points to the right element as your `button` doesn't have an `id`. Do you want to make the `button` or your nested `span` editable?

Comment: `$(#editable2).click(function(){ $(this).attr('contentEditable',true); }) .blur(function(){ $(this).attr('contentEditable', false); })` This is my code inside the `$('#button').click` function. But it's not working for me.

Comment: You forgot the quotes around `#editable2` but I still don't see the point in trying to make a nested `<span>` inside a `<button>` editable, why don't you make the whole `<button>` editable as per the provided JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I've now edited my code, the `button` now has the `id`and I've erased the `span`, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: What does the console tell you?

Comment: It doesn't give a message in the console though.

Comment: Does an alert work on click on the button? If it doesn't, the problem comes from the jQuery identifier `$("editable2").` or `if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') )` and thus not related with the subject of this topic. Are you sure `$.count` equals `2`?

Comment: I manage to determine the error, I think having an attribute draggable and at the same time contenteditable, doesn't work.

Comment: I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

This is it.

```html
    <button contenteditable>Hello</button>
```